# Reshaping RDD from an array of array to unique columns in pySpark

Tags: pyspark, rdd, transformation

I want to use `pySpark` to restructure my data so that I can use it for `MLLib` models, currently for each user I have an array of array in one column and I want to convert it unique columns with the count.

```
Users | column1                  |
user1 | [[name1, 4], [name2, 5]] |
user2 | [[name1, 2], [name3, 1]] |
```

should get converted to:

```
Users | name1   | name2   | name3   |
user1 | 4.0     | 5.0     | 0.0     |
user2 | 2.0     | 0.0     | 1.0     |
```

I came up with a method that uses for loops but I am looking for a way that can utilize spark because the data is huge. Could you give me any hints? Thanks.

Edit: 
All of the unique names should come as individual columns with the score corresponding to each user. Basically, a sparse matrix.
I am working with pandas right now and the code I'm using to do this is

```
data = data.applymap(lambda x: dict(x))    # To convert the array of array into a dictionary
columns = list(data)
for i in columns:
    # For each columns using the dictionary to make a new Series and appending it to the current dataframe
    data = pd.concat([data.drop([i], axis=1), data[i].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: @CKE, thank you for replying. Sorry, this is my first time posting a question. Does this look okay now?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Do you know the column names that will be created beforehand or can it vary according to data. Example: `name1`, `name2`, `name3` and so on.

Comment: It can vary according to data

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
# First we explode column`, this makes each element as a separate row
df= df.withColumn('column1', F.explode_outer(F.col('column1')))
# Then, seperate out the new column1 into two columns
df = df.withColumn(("column1_seperated"), F.col('column1')[0])
df= df.withColumn("count", F.col(i)['column1'].cast(IntegerType()))
# Then pivot the df
df= df.groupby('Users').pivot("column1_seperated").sum('count')
```